# How to have 3 columns layout with left and right column sticky to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-position, sticky

I have a 3 column layout and in the center column, I'm adding content when the scroll gets to the end like infinite scroll. Now I need to get sticky left and right columns at the bottom but putting position: sticky, bottom: 0px is not doing anything for me. I change the parent height to 100hv to always maintain the viewport high and not the one that is growing every time that I add some content in the middle column, but still is not working. Can I get some ideas or basic examples?

I want to accomplish this in this example.

```css
.App {
text-align: center;
}
.topheader {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  background: yellow;
  width: 540px;
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">
    <div class="App">
      <div class="topheader"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="box">1</div>
          <div class="box">2</div>
          <div class="box">2</div>
          <div class="box">2</div>
          <div class="box">2</div>
          <div class="box">stick here at bottom</div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
          <div class="box">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="box">3</div>
          <div class="box">4</div>
          <div class="box">4</div>
          <div class="box">4</div>
          <div class="box">stick here at bottom</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

The desire behavior is that when I scroll down and the bottom of the viewport reach the bottom part of left and right columns(stick here at bottom) get sticked there the left and right column and continue scrolling to see the center content.

Comment: provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: I added a reproducible example, thanks.

Comment: using `top: max(calc(100% - 1000px),0px);` along with position sticky will keep it at the bottom (1000px should be the height of the div), maybe that with some javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: sticky`

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="item shark-1">
     <img src="/images/punk.png" width="100" alt="Sammy the Shark with a pun theme.">
   </div>
   <div class="item shark-2">
      <img src="/images/pony.png" width="100" alt="Sammy the Shark with a magical pony theme.">
 </div>
 <div class="item shark-3">
    <img src="/images/dino.png" width="100" alt="Sammy the Shark with a dinosaur   theme.">
 </div>
 <div class="item shark-4">
   <img src="/images/steampunk.png" width="100" alt="Sammy the Shark with a steampunk theme.">
 </div>
</div>


 CSS:
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 2px dashed rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.35);
   height: 400px;
   background: rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.05);
 }

 .item { position: sticky;}
 .shark-1 { top: 0;}
 .shark-2 {top: 4rem;
 .shark-3 { bottom: 1rem; align-self: flex-end;}
```